# Area stacking order and tooltip

Tags: graph, highcharts, time-series

I am making a stacked area graph. 
series A should be under series B

Since it's not possible to invert the stacking order I had to reverse the series order so that  chart.series[0] is the series B and chart.series[1](http://jsfiddle.net/3fd6L/) series A.

I can reverse the order of the legend to present the series A before series B.

But I still have a problem with the shared tooltip where the series A is displayed below the series B.

Is there a solution to change the order of the tooltip ?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var char_option={chart:{type:null,
renderTo:"container",
zoomType:"xy",
marginTop:100,
height:500,
margin:{marginLeft:0},
backgroundColor:"transparent"},    
tooltip:{xDateFormat:"%d\/%m\/%Y %H:%M",
shared:true,
crosshairs:{color:"orange",
width:1},
snap:50,
formatter:null,
useHTML:true,
backgroundColor:"rgba(241,243,248,0.85)"},
title:null,
legend:{reversed:true},
xAxis:[{gridLineWidth:null,
gridLineDashStyle:"Dash",
type:"datetime",
gridLineColor:"#C0D0E0",
plotBands:[],
plotLines:[],
title:[],
minRange:600000,
maxPadding:0.05,
opposite:false,
lineColor:"#C0D0E0",
lineWidth:0,
tickColor:"#C0D0E0",
tickInterval:null,
tickPosition:"outside",
pointPadding:null,
groupPadding:null,
borderWidth:null,
formatter:null,
endOnTick:null,
categories:null,
reversed:false,
tickLength:5,
minTickInterval:null,
min:1364947200000,
max:1365033600000}],
yAxis:[{gridLineWidth:1,
gridLineDashStyle:"Solid",
type:"linear",
labels:{formatter:function() {return this.value;}},
title:{text:"Temps (ms)"},
min:null,
max:null,
gridLineColor:"#C0D0E0",
plotBands:[],
plotLines:[],
minRange:null,
maxPadding:0.05,
opposite:false,
lineColor:"#C0D0E0",
lineWidth:0,
tickColor:"#C0D0E0",
tickInterval:null,
tickPosition:"outside",
pointPadding:null,
groupPadding:null,
borderWidth:null,
formatter:null,
endOnTick:null,
categories:null,
reversed:false,
tickLength:5,
minTickInterval:null},
{gridLineWidth:1,
gridLineDashStyle:"Solid",
type:"linear",
labels:{enabled:true},
title:{text:"nbr Anomalies"},
min:null,
max:null,
gridLineColor:"transparent",
plotBands:[],
plotLines:[],
minRange:null,
maxPadding:0.05,
opposite:true,
lineColor:"#FF0000",
lineWidth:0,
tickColor:"#00FF00",
tickInterval:null,
tickPosition:"outside",
pointPadding:0,
groupPadding:0,
borderWidth:0,
formatter:null,
endOnTick:null,
categories:null,
reversed:false,
tickLength:0,
minTickInterval:1}],
plotOptions:{area:{marker:{enabled:true,
radius:1},
lineWidth:1,
connectNulls:false,
shadow:false,
fillOpacity:0.3,
zIndex:1},
areaspline:{marker:{enabled:false},
lineWidth:1,
connectNulls:false,
shadow:false,
fillOpacity:0.3,
zIndex:1},
series:{connectNulls:false,
marker:{lineColor:"orange",
states:{hover:{fillColor:"orange",
radius:1}}}},
line:{marker:{enabled:true,
radius:1},
lineWidth:1,
connectNulls:0,
shadow:false,
fillOpacity:0.3,
zIndex:1},
column:{pointPlacement:"on",
marker:{enabled:true},
borderWidth:1,
shadow:false,
fillOpacity:0.3,
zIndex:0}},
series:[{data:[{x:1364983200000,
y:1,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364992200000,
y:1,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364995800000,
y:1,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365003000000,
y:1,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365004800000,
y:1,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365005700000,
y:1,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
DayTimestamp:1364947200000}],
xAxis:0,
yAxis:1,
index:0,
name:"Anomalies",
type:"column",
color:"rgba(193,50,50,0.7)",
zIndex:0,
stacking:"normal",
legend:null,
borderWidth:1,
fillOpacity:0.3,
borderColor:"rgba(216,28,28,0.5)",
pointPadding:0,
groupPadding:null,
dataLabels:[],
tooltip:null,
marker:{enabled:false},
showInLegend:true,
point:{events:{click:function(event){ NewOpenDetail(event) }}},
turboThreshold:1500},
{data:[{x:1364947200000,
y:3063,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364948100000,
y:2156.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364949000000,
y:1546.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364949900000,
y:1937.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364950800000,
y:1593.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364951700000,
y:2078,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364952600000,
y:1906,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364953500000,
y:1703,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364954400000,
y:1891,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364955300000,
y:1711,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364956200000,
y:2109,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364957100000,
y:2008,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364958000000,
y:1781.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364958900000,
y:2000,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364959800000,
y:1672,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364960700000,
y:2000,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364961600000,
y:1531,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364962500000,
y:1485,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364963400000,
y:3367,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364964300000,
y:1687.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364965200000,
y:1929.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364966100000,
y:2015.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364967000000,
y:1640.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364967900000,
y:2500,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364968800000,
y:1765.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364969700000,
y:1789,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364970600000,
y:2383,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364971500000,
y:3359.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364972400000,
y:1742.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364973300000,
y:1844,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364974200000,
y:4101.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364975100000,
y:2062.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364976000000,
y:1719,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364976900000,
y:2008,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364977800000,
y:1476.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364978700000,
y:1570,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364979600000,
y:1726,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364980500000,
y:3477,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364981400000,
y:10735,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364982300000,
y:1609,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364983200000,
y:3531,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364984100000,
y:2859.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364985000000,
y:1547,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364985900000,
y:1766,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364986800000,
y:2445.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364987700000,
y:1406,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364988600000,
y:2922,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364989500000,
y:2696,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364990400000,
y:1414,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364991300000,
y:5109.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364992200000,
y:4797,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364993100000,
y:7491.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364994000000,
y:1719,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364994900000,
y:3883,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364995800000,
y:1469,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364996700000,
y:1484.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364997600000,
y:1523.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364998500000,
y:1633,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364999400000,
y:2374.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365000300000,
y:2047,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365001200000,
y:2508,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365002100000,
y:5343.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365003000000,
y:2000,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365003900000,
y:2133,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365004800000,
y:1688,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365005700000,
y:2047,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365006600000,
y:2851.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365007500000,
y:1906,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365008400000,
y:1750,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365009300000,
y:2758,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365010200000,
y:2336.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365011100000,
y:1586,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365012000000,
y:1750,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365012900000,
y:2031,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365013800000,
y:1820.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365014700000,
y:1460.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365015600000,
y:1601.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365016500000,
y:2054.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365017400000,
y:1562,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365018300000,
y:1929.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365019200000,
y:1859.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365020100000,
y:1976.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365021000000,
y:2062.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365021900000,
y:1555,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365022800000,
y:2562.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365023700000,
y:2484.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365024600000,
y:6023.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365025500000,
y:14460.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365026400000,
y:3257.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365027300000,
y:4679.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365028200000,
y:1672,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365029100000,
y:2093.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365030000000,
y:2078.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365030900000,
y:2062.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365031800000,
y:1679.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365032700000,
y:2062.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
DayTimestamp:1364947200000}],
xAxis:0,
yAxis:0,
index:0,
name:"2 - Contacts",
type:"area",
color:"#0700A5",
zIndex:1,
stacking:"normal",
legend:null,
borderWidth:null,
fillOpacity:0.3,
borderColor:null,
pointPadding:null,
groupPadding:null,
dataLabels:[],
tooltip:{useHTML:true,
valueSuffix:" ms",
pointFormat:"<div class='cartouche'><div style='background-color:{series.color};height:10px;width:10px;float:left;'></div><span>{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</span></div>"},
marker:{enabled:false},
showInLegend:true,
point:{events:{click:function(event){ NewOpenDetail(event) }}},
turboThreshold:1500},
{data:[{x:1364947200000,
y:11132.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364948100000,
y:8664.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364949000000,
y:8656,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364949900000,
y:8242.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364950800000,
y:7874.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364951700000,
y:8562.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364952600000,
y:9648.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364953500000,
y:8563,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364954400000,
y:9531,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364955300000,
y:7843.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364956200000,
y:7578,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364957100000,
y:8219,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364958000000,
y:7398.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364958900000,
y:10328,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364959800000,
y:7961.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364960700000,
y:8953,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364961600000,
y:7688,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364962500000,
y:8609.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364963400000,
y:7874.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364964300000,
y:7992,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364965200000,
y:8171.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364966100000,
y:8835.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364967000000,
y:8180,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364967900000,
y:7719,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364968800000,
y:8641,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364969700000,
y:9468.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364970600000,
y:7460.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364971500000,
y:10578,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364972400000,
y:7523.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364973300000,
y:7391,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364974200000,
y:11734,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364975100000,
y:7547,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364976000000,
y:8187.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364976900000,
y:8390.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364977800000,
y:7679.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364978700000,
y:8602,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364979600000,
y:6734.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364980500000,
y:8945,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364981400000,
y:11860,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364982300000,
y:8406,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364983200000,
y:14031,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364984100000,
y:12039,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364985000000,
y:9078,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364985900000,
y:6516,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364986800000,
y:8109,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364987700000,
y:7516,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364988600000,
y:13992,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364989500000,
y:12617.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364990400000,
y:7804.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364991300000,
y:8453,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364992200000,
y:11101.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364993100000,
y:6414,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364994000000,
y:7195.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364994900000,
y:7679.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364995800000,
y:9453,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364996700000,
y:8922,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364997600000,
y:10000,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364998500000,
y:11226.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1364999400000,
y:8171.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365000300000,
y:13250,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365001200000,
y:7929.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365002100000,
y:10125,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365003000000,
y:9156,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365003900000,
y:8445.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365004800000,
y:14421,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365005700000,
y:6656,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365006600000,
y:8507.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365007500000,
y:10843.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365008400000,
y:9211,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365009300000,
y:9320,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365010200000,
y:8656.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365011100000,
y:6570.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365012000000,
y:7601.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365012900000,
y:9609.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365013800000,
y:7625,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365014700000,
y:7601.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365015600000,
y:6453,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365016500000,
y:9328.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365017400000,
y:8313,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365018300000,
y:6367,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365019200000,
y:8156,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365020100000,
y:9492.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365021000000,
y:7195,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365021900000,
y:7203,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365022800000,
y:7719,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365023700000,
y:8828.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365024600000,
y:7164,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365025500000,
y:6656.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365026400000,
y:8242,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365027300000,
y:7344,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365028200000,
y:7359,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365029100000,
y:8507.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365030000000,
y:9132.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365030900000,
y:8281.5,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365031800000,
y:8016,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
},
{x:1365032700000,
y:8367,
localTmin:1364947200000,
localTmax:1365033600000,
DayTimestamp:1364947200000}],
xAxis:0,
yAxis:0,
index:0,
name:"1 - http:\/\/www.groupe.caisse-epargne.fr\/",
type:"area",
color:"#564EFF",
zIndex:1,
stacking:"normal",
legend:null,
borderWidth:null,
fillOpacity:0.3,
borderColor:null,
pointPadding:null,
groupPadding:null,
dataLabels:[],
tooltip:{useHTML:true,
valueSuffix:" ms",
pointFormat:"<div class='cartouche'><div style='background-color:{series.color};height:10px;width:10px;float:left;'></div><span>{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</span></div>"},
marker:{enabled:false},
showInLegend:true,
point:{events:{click:function(event){ NewOpenDetail(event) }}},
turboThreshold:1500}],
colors:["#FFC000",
"#FF8300",
"#4B41FF",
"#8DC6FF",
"#AB0000",
"#615EB0",
"#FCE151",
"#FFBA00",
"#FF9724",
"#E39810",
"#DF5300",
"#F10000",
"#94211A",
"#4A411B",
"#015F1B",
"#298A2F",
"#869420",
"#83803B",
"#806460",
"#782FA7",
"#7309DB",
"#5900B0",
"#FFC000",
"#FF8300",
"#4B41FF",
"#8DC6FF",
"#AB0000",
"#615EB0",
"#FCE151",
"#FFBA00",
"#FF9724",
"#E39810",
"#DF5300",
"#F10000",
"#94211A",
"#4A411B",
"#015F1B",
"#298A2F",
"#869420",
"#83803B",
"#806460",
"#782FA7",
"#7309DB",
"#5900B0"]}
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(char_option);
})
```

Fiddle [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/3fd6L/)

Comment: I'm just wondering why you cannot change series order? Also you can use index http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.index

Comment: the series order has a meaning : i want the second serie to be stacked on top of the first one